# Python-String to Bytes conversion. Double BackSlash issue

Tags: python, string, byte

I've got a problem. I've this string:

```
a=O\x8c\x90\x05\xa1\xe2!\xbe
```

If i use:

```
c=str.encode(a)
```

This is the result:

```
b'O\\x8c\\x90\\x05\\xa1\\xe2!\\xbe'
```

I need those double backslash to be single backslash and i really need that type of data to be BYTES. I need to return this:

```
c=b'0\x8c\x90\x05\xa1\xe2!\xbe'
```

And type(c)==bytes
Any idea?

Comment: what does `print(repr(a))` give?

Comment: Sry. This: 'O\\x8c\\x90\\x05\\xa1\\xe2!\\xbe'

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `str.decode()` with encoding as `unicode-escape` . Then decode it back using the required encoding to get back your bytes array. Example -

```
c = a.decode('unicode-escape').encode('<required encoding>')
```

Demo -

```
>>> a
b'O\\x8c\\x90\\x05\\xa1\\xe2!\\xbe'
>>> c = a.decode('unicode-escape').encode('ISO-8859-1')
>>> c
b'O\x8c\x90\x05\xa1\xe2!\xbe'
```

Comment: Nvm. didn't notice c is Bytes.

Comment: Still not getting what i want. I need this output --> c=b'0\x8c\x90\x05\xa1\xe2!\xbe' Your solution gives me this: b'O\xc2\x8c\xc2\x90\x05\xc2\xa1\xc3\xa2!\xc2\xbe'

Comment: Thats because `\xe2` is not valid `utf-8` . Use a valid encoding and it should work

Comment: @TeoAlbano Check now, using `ISO-8859-1` should work.

Comment: You are a GOD.

If you are dumping and data via DUMP in Redis and you're trying to RESTORE it, you will absolutely need to decode, then encode it back using `ISO-8859-1`.