# Storing string from stdin with backslashes into variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte, shellcode

How could I store strings in the format "\x00\xc1\xeb" into a variable encoded/converted into bytes?

It seems python has trouble parsing the backslashes correctly.

What I've tried:

```
bytes_input = bytes(input('enter byte string'), 'utf-8')
```

I'm trying to store shellcode into the variable 'bytes_input' I think the backslashes are causing issues because they're being interpreter as escape string.

When I print the variable 'bytes_input' the output is:

```
b'"\\x00\\xc1\\xeb"'
```

The intended output should be:

```
b"\x00\xc1\xeb"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Find the solution in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257875/python-string-to-bytes-conversion-double-backslash-issue)

Find my code also for reference.

```
string_input = str(input('Enter string:'))
string_value = string_input if string_input else '\\x00\\xc1\\xeb'

print("Input String: {}".format(string_value))

encoded_value = string_value.encode('utf-8')
print(encoded_value.decode('unicode-escape').encode("ISO-8859-1"))
```