# ValueError: Ciphertext length must be equal to key size

Tags: python, cryptography, rsa

I know this question was asked a lot, but I still don't really understand how could I debug my code. I was googling this question for over 3 days now, but I just can't find a suitable answer for my code. I want to add the encrypted message with an input but every time I run my code it just gives the

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decryption.py", line 27, in <module>
    label=None
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 357, in decrypt
    raise ValueError("Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.")
ValueError: Ciphertext length must be equal to key size.
```

error. I know its with the label, but I just can't find the answer
Here is my code for the decryption:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding

with open("private_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    private_key = serialization.load_pem_private_key(
        key_file.read(),
        password=None,
        backend=default_backend()
    )
with open("public_key.pem", "rb") as key_file:
    public_key = serialization.load_pem_public_key(
        key_file.read(),
        backend=default_backend()
    )

textInput = str(input(">>> "))
encrypted = textInput.encode() 


original_message = private_key.decrypt(
    encrypted,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)

original_decoded_message = original_message.decode("utf-8")

print(original_decoded_message)
```

And for the encryption:

```
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import hashes
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization

private_key = rsa.generate_private_key(
    public_exponent=65537,
    key_size=2048,
    backend=default_backend()
)
public_key = private_key.public_key()


pem = private_key.private_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PrivateFormat.PKCS8,
    encryption_algorithm=serialization.NoEncryption()
)
with open('private_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)

pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)
with open('public_key.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(pem)


raw_message = str(input(">>> "))
message = raw_message.encode("utf-8")

encrypted = public_key.encrypt(
    message,
    padding.OAEP(
        mgf=padding.MGF1(algorithm=hashes.SHA256()),
        algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
        label=None
    )
)


print(encrypted)
```

Im really new to Asymmetric encryption / decryption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This minor modification in the decryption part of your code made it work for me:

```
textInput = str(input(">>> "))
# encrypted = textInput.encode()  #this is incorrect!
encrypted = eval(textInput)
```

This is what I get:

For the encryption part:

```
>>> test message
b'>xB)\xf1\xc5I\xd6\xce\xfb\xcf\x83\xe2\xc5\x8f\xcfl\xb9\x0f\xa2\x13\xa5\xe1\x03\xf7p\xb3\x9c\xeb\r\xc1"\xf2\x17\x8b\xea\t\xed\xb2xG\xb7\r\xa9\xf8\x03eBD\xdd9>\xbe\xd1O\xe2\x9f\xbb\xf9\xff5\x96l\xea\x17FI\x8d\x02\x05\xea\x1dpM\xbb\x04J\xfc\x0c\\\xfe\x15\x07\xaf \x9e\xc2\xf9M\xa4\x1d$\xc3\x99my\xb6\xc5\xad\x97\xd06\xd2\x08\xd3\xe2\xc8H\xca\xd8\xfd{\xe6\xc6\xa3\x18\xeb\xe6\xcc\xc5\x9a\xc8*\xbb\xc1\x8c\x80,\x1f\r@\x9b\x9d\xc5\x91I\xa8\xc01y\xbc\xa73\xd3\x19;\xef\x8a\xfb\xc2\xc4\x9e\xbe\x8f\xeb\x1d\x12\xbd\xe4<\xa0\xbb\x8d\xef\xee\xa3\x89E\x07"m\x1d\xb0\xf3\xd2:y\xd9\xbd\xef\xdf\xc9\xbb\x1b\xd5\x03\x91\xa4l\x8bS\x9e\x80\x14\x90\x18\xc4\x9e\\?\x8eF\x05\xa1H\x9e:\x0c\x96\x8e\xb3E3\x90\xa2\xa1\xd9\x88\xa0<X\x7f\rIP\x00\xbf\xf6\x15\xfb9tW\x17\x9f\xca\x95\xf6|\xd7\x90\xbcp\xe5\xb5,V\x1b\xe9\x90\xf6\x87 v=6'
```

Now for the decryption part, I use the output:

```
>>> b'>xB)\xf1\xc5I\xd6\xce\xfb\xcf\x83\xe2\xc5\x8f\xcfl\xb9\x0f\xa2\x13\xa5\xe1\x03\xf7p\xb3\x9c\xeb\r\xc1"\xf2\x17\x8b\xea\t\xed\xb2xG\xb7\r\xa9\xf8\x03eBD\xdd9>\xbe\xd1O\xe2\x9f\xbb\xf9\xff5\x96l\xea\x17FI\x8d\x02\x05\xea\x1dpM\xbb\x04J\xfc\x0c\\\xfe\x15\x07\xaf \x9e\xc2\xf9M\xa4\x1d$\xc3\x99my\xb6\xc5\xad\x97\xd06\xd2\x08\xd3\xe2\xc8H\xca\xd8\xfd{\xe6\xc6\xa3\x18\xeb\xe6\xcc\xc5\x9a\xc8*\xbb\xc1\x8c\x80,\x1f\r@\x9b\x9d\xc5\x91I\xa8\xc01y\xbc\xa73\xd3\x19;\xef\x8a\xfb\xc2\xc4\x9e\xbe\x8f\xeb\x1d\x12\xbd\xe4<\xa0\xbb\x8d\xef\xee\xa3\x89E\x07"m\x1d\xb0\xf3\xd2:y\xd9\xbd\xef\xdf\xc9\xbb\x1b\xd5\x03\x91\xa4l\x8bS\x9e\x80\x14\x90\x18\xc4\x9e\\?\x8eF\x05\xa1H\x9e:\x0c\x96\x8e\xb3E3\x90\xa2\xa1\xd9\x88\xa0<X\x7f\rIP\x00\xbf\xf6\x15\xfb9tW\x17\x9f\xca\x95\xf6|\xd7\x90\xbcp\xe5\xb5,V\x1b\xe9\x90\xf6\x87 v=6'
test message
```

The problem with your original code is that you are writing the *representation* of a bytes string as a unicode string (when using `print(encrypted)`), then encoding it into a bytes object in the decrypt code, and then passing it to the decrypt function. Encoding this string will not yield the original bytes string `encrypted`.

This example illustrates the problem:

```
>>> x = bytes(bytearray.fromhex('f3'))
>>> x #A bytes string, similar to encrypt
b'\xf3'
>>> print(x)
b'\xf3'
>>> len(x)
1
>>> str(x) #this is what print(x) writes to stdout
"b'\\xf3'"
>>> print(str(x))
b'\xf3'
>>> len(str(x)) #Note that the lengths are different!
7 
>>> x == str(x)
False
>>> str(x).encode() #what you were trying to do
b"b'\\xf3'"
>>> x == str(x).encode()
False
>>> eval(str(x)) #what gets the desired result
b'\xf3'
>>> x == eval(str(x))
True
```

The thing is that the [`print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) function prints the *representation* of the object rather than the object itself. Essentially, it does this by getting a printable value of inherently unprintable objects by using [`__repr__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) or [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) methods of that object.

This is the documentation for `__str__`:

> Called by `str(object)` and the built-in functions `format()` and `print()`
>   to compute the “informal” or nicely printable string representation of
>   an object. The return value must be a string object.
>    .
>    .
>   The default
>   implementation defined by the built-in type object calls
>   `object.__repr__()`.

and `__repr__`:

> Called by the `repr()` built-in function to compute the “official”
>   string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should
>   look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an
>   object

This "official" representation returned by `__repr__` is what allowed me to use the [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) function in the decrypt code to solve the problem.

**TL;DR**:
copying the output of `print(encrypted)` copies the informal, human readable value returned by `encrypted.__str__()` or the "official" representation returned by `encrypted.__repr__()`, which are both in a human readable encoding such as `utf-8`. They cannot be encoded back(by using `utf-8` encoding) to create the original bytes string that they represent.

It is also worth looking into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33257875/python-string-to-bytes-conversion-double-backslash-issue) question from a stackoverflow user, facing the same issue. The answer gives a way to actually encode this representation back into a bytes object if you want. It's worth looking into this because `eval` should be avoided, it is very [unsafe](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). For that method to work, you would have to remove the leading `b'` and trailing `'` from the string `textInput` before encoding it.

My final recommendation would be to pass the entire object `encrypted` between the two programs by either using files with the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) module, or some form of socket programming. Best to stay away from using `print` and `input` to pass data like this between programs to avoid encoding issues.

Comment: Good detailed answer. Just to add to the last part about passing the encrypted data: if it's done manually (Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V), or on a higher level than raw sockets (REST API?), a base64 encoding is a simple option. It's easy and safe to pass a base64-encoded string and then decode it back to bytes before decrypting. For the OP this would be the best option, and no need to `eval()` anything. `eval()` is dangerous.